# Reference Values in Helm method

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I'm trying to reference a value from my Values.yaml file in Helm in a Files.Glob method.

Here is my Configmap template:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm
data:
  {{- tpl ((.Files.Glob "qa.ns1/*").AsConfig) . | nindent 2 }}
```

The above works as expected.

The folder structure is "environment.namespace". ns1 is the name of my namespace. How do I reference a value from my Values.yaml file instead of ns1?

I have tried:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm
data:
  {{- tpl ((.Files.Glob "qa.{{ .Values.namespace }}/*").AsConfig) . | nindent 2 }}
```

Where my Values.yaml file is:

```
namespace: ns1
```

I get no data in my configmap when I reference it with above. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the [Go text/template](https://godoc.org/text/template) `printf` function.  Split out into variables this would look like:

```
data:
  {{- $glob := printf "qa.%s/*" .Values.Namespace }}
  {{- $data := (.Files.Glob $glob).AsConfig }}
  {{- tpl $data . | nindent 2 }}
```

The [Sprig `cat` function](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/strings.html) would also work

```
{{- $glob := cat "qa." .Values.Namespace "/*" }}
```

Once you're inside the `{{ ... }}` template block, you can't nest template blocks, but you can just directly refer to variables and Helm values.

Comment: thanks @David Maze !

your answer works for directory names that don't have period in them. Its working if the directory name is "qans1". Im not getting any data in the configmap with "qa.ns1"